# asp.net code executes very fast on development while very slow on production

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code to build a large string. it runs well on my development pc, about taking 2 seconds to complete all tasks, but when I put them on production server, it will take 10-20 seconds depending on something unknown. The time is calculated from TimePoint1 to TimePoint2.

BTW: abstractTable.GetWordCountInList(listID) just contains one line:  return 100;

All other functions on production server work ok, except for this one. 
Oracle DB server and Web Server are on the same machine, and the query returns about 5000 records. Product server's data is same as the development server.

```
public const string WordXMLItemTemplate = @"<S I=""{0}"" W=""{1}"" L=""{2}"" F=""0"" P=""0"" />";   

int totalCounter =0;
int wordCounter = 0;
int listID = 1;
OracleConnection wordLibConn = ConnectionManager.GetNewConnection();
wordLibConn.Open();
try
{
    OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand();
    comm.Connection = wordLibConn;
    comm.CommandText = "Select WordID from WordTable Order By Lower(Word) ASC";
    OracleDataReader dataReader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        // TimePoint 1
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            totalCounter++;
            wordCounter++;
            wordXML = wordXML + string.Format(WordXMLItemTemplate, totalCounter, dataReader[0].ToString(), listID);
            if (wordCounter % abstractTable.GetWordCountInList(listID) == 0)
            {
                wordCounter = 0;
                listID++;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        dataReader.Close();
    }
}
finally
{
    wordLibConn.Close();
}
// TimePoint 2
```

I suffered from the problem for months, thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: Do you have exclusive use of your production server? i.e. Are other sites running on it? Also, is your DB server on the same LAN? Please include descriptions of your local/live setup so we can see where some of the issues may lay.

Comment: What is the difference in production data vs dev data?  Is production much larger?

Comment: Have you considered using StringBuilder for large string construction? it's much more efficient than simple concatenating strings

Comment: @maccettura  the data are same on dev and production, about 5000 records.

Comment: So what is the point of the `wordCounter`, it would, in theory, create a new word list every 100 words?

Comment: @LeeTaylor db server and web server are on the same machine.

Comment: @KarlAnderson correct, i want to create a list every 100 words.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I am considering to use StringBuilder, but before the change, I just want to find out what causes the problem, for the code runs very well on dev pc.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out all of the code inside of the `while (dataReader.Read())` loop? Do the timing and see if is improved or not, if so, then add in each commented out portion until the bottleneck is found.

Comment: As a side note - why you don't have the wordLibConn.Open(); inside the try block?

Comment: Could there be some sort of buffersize issue?  The dev box getting everything in one grab and the production box using multiple trips to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list for yourself of the potential lines or code fragments which might cause this slowness. Measure all of them and take a look at the results of your measures. Hopefully you will find the exact place where the stalling is caused and you will be closer to the solution.

Comment: Finally, I solved the problem by replacing string+string by StringBuilder. However, I still can't understand, why string+string worked well on dev machine, but took 10 more seconds on production server.